# WSO2 Identity server Error starting LDAP server

Tags: wso2-identity-server

installed Wso2 as shown in wso2 documentation, changed the default db to mssql and now i keep getting errors on trying to restart the server

it is running on ubuntu

```
ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.apacheds.impl.ApacheLDAPServer} -  Error starting LDAP server.
org.apache.directory.shared.ldap.exception.LdapConfigurationException: ERR_171 Failed to bind an LDAP service (10,389) to the service registry.
        at org.apache.directory.server.ldap.LdapServer.startNetwork(LdapServer.java:582)

ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm} -  nullType class java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: nullType class java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.createObjectWithOptions(DefaultRealm.java:395)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.initializeObjects(DefaultRealm.java:222)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.init(DefaultRealm.java:127)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.initializeRealm(DefaultRealmService.java:264)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.<init>(DefaultRealmService.java:102)
```

[

```
2019-08-26 15:59:40,317] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.Activator} -  Cannot start User Manager Core bundle
org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Cannot initialize the realm.
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.initializeRealm(DefaultRealmService.java:274)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.<init>(DefaultRealmService.java:102)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.<init>(DefaultRealmService.java:115)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.Activator.startDeploy(Activator.java:72)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.BundleCheckActivator.start(BundleCheckActivator.java:61)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
```

i have put bits of the errors i get when starting the server
please can anyone help i am new to this

Comment: Did you change the user-mgt.xml file? By default, we use a file-based LDAP as the user store. If you are going to change the Primary User store to JDBC, first you have to comment on the LDAP configurations and then uncomment the JDBC user store configurations in the user-mgt.xml file

Comment: As error suggest this is may be due to some another service using the port 10389. (Which is used by the embedded LDAP in the Identity Server). Please check that. Or else you can add a port offset to change the port number in the carbon.xml file.

Comment: Check whether there is any other service using the 10389 port. If there is a service and you don't want it, stop the service and try starting the WSO2 server again. Or else, you can try adding a port offset as @JayangaKaushalya has mentioned above.

Comment: no i have not changed anything besides the DB, i changed that to MSSQl, do i need to edit the user-mgt.xml file @Dinali Dabarera

Comment: there's nothing using the port, how do i do the port offset @Jayanga Kaushalya

Comment: Please check the following documentation for changing ports using port offset. 
https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS5xx/Default+Ports+of+WSO2+Products

Answer (score 0):

Could you check if you have followed the steps given in this guide when changing the default DB to MSSQL?

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/ADMIN44x/Changing+to+MSSQL